# Seagate Hard Drive RPM

Tags: hard-disk, backup

I'm looking to replace a backup drive that died. I was considering a Seagate Barracuda drive (ST2000DM001) which is listed as 7200 RPM. Amazon reports a newer version of the drive (ST2000DM006), which is about the same price, but it doesn't list the RPM.

I looked up the spec sheet on the drive, and it doesn't have this information either:

http://www.seagate.com/www-content/product-content/barracuda-fam/barracuda-new/files/barracuda-ds-1900-1-1606us.pdf

Is this newer version of the drive recommended? Does anybody know what the differences are here? Why aren't they reporting the RPM?

So, I'm asking whether I should purchase the newer version of the drive or the older one. Does anyone know if there will be a performance difference?

Clarification: I'm looking for a faster and more reliable drive since I will be often be transferring large amounts of data when backing up, and I need my backup drive to be reliable. Other drive recommendations are also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry I don't have a source on this as it's more of a result of long experience in the industry than anything else I can really point to, documentation-wise (so if someone else comes along with a document-supported answer, obviously upvote that answer, not this one), but I am 100% confident that both drives are running at 7200rpm. The difference in model number probably only denotes a difference in OEM part supplier change, likely in the controller chip or PCB, as these are things which are swapped out all the time and not necessarily made in-house at Seagate. For what it's worth, here are the data sheets for [ST2000DM001](http://www.seagate.com/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/desktop-hdd-8tbDS1770-9-1603US-en_US.pdf) and [ST2000DM006](http://www.seagate.com/www-content/product-content/barracuda-fam/barracuda-new/files/barracuda-ds-1900-1-1606us.pdf). Controller identification is not provided, but performance data is. They are both 7200rpm drives, they are both listed as providing the same reads, writes, warranty, etc. Given that all else appears the same, I advise you to choose the cheaper of the two drives. If they are the same price, choose the newer ST2000DM006 since support for it might be longer.

Answer (score 2):

This questions has already been answered but here is concrete information provided from seagate.

I also agree with the answer.

Screen Shot 2016-07-22 at 1.58.13 PM.png[image]